# Cant move in google maps activity. It always return to my current location

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-activity

I'm working on app which include google maps activity.

**My problem is:** 
When I'm trying to move around in the map or zoom in & out it immediately return to my current location. Also when I search for location, new marker added at the searched location but immediately goes back to my current location.

I searched for solution but found nothing.. 
I hope somebody can figure it out

This is my google maps activity:

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    public LocationManager locationManager;
    public LocationListener locationListener;
    public DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private ArrayList<User> userArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    User useri;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == 1) {

            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title("המיקום שלי")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_action_marker1)));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 11));

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

            }
        };

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        } else {

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

            }
            else {

                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
                //mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                //MapStyleOptions style = MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.style);
                //mMap.setMapStyle(style);
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                final Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
                final LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), lastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
                mDatabase.child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("lat").setValue(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude());
                mDatabase.child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("lng").setValue(lastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
                mMap.clear();
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title("המיקום שלי")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_action_marker1)));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 11));

                showUsersOnMap();

            }
        }
    }


    // Search for location and show it on the map
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if(view.getId() == R.id.searchLocationBtn){
            EditText searchBoxLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchBoxLocation);
            String location = searchBoxLocation.getText().toString();
            List<Address> addressList = null;
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            if( ! location.equals("")){
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
                try {
                    addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                for (int i = 0 ; i < addressList.size(); i++){
                    Address myAddress = addressList.get(i);
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(myAddress.getLatitude(), myAddress.getLongitude());
                    markerOptions.position(latLng);
                    mMap.clear();
                    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,11));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Function to show all the users on the map
    public void showUsersOnMap(){
        mDatabase.child("Users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    User user = ds.getValue(User.class);
                    userArrayList.add(user);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < userArrayList.size(); i++) {
                    useri = userArrayList.get(i);
                    if (useri.getLat() != 0  && useri.getLng() != 0) {
                        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                        LatLng userlatLng = new LatLng(useri.getLat(), useri.getLng());
                        markerOptions.position(userlatLng);
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userlatLng).title(useri.getName()).snippet(useri.getPhone())
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_action_marker2)));
                        //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng2,10));

                    }
                    else Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ישנה בעיה. אנא נסה להתחבר למפה שוב",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I think I found what was the problem.
I just disabled the mMap.moveCamera() inside onLocationChanged() and it works just fine.

Now Im wondering if its ok to do so? its still keep the camera on my current location when I Drive for example?

Answer (score 0):

In your search code you are adding marker every time in the loop

```
 for (int i = 0 ; i < addressList.size(); i++){
                    Address myAddress = addressList.get(i);
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(myAddress.getLatitude(), myAddress.getLongitude());
                    markerOptions.position(latLng);
                    mMap.clear();
                    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,11));
                }
```

In the same code, you are moving the camera to a specific location `mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,11))`

`mMap.addMarker()` will add a new marker to map.

`mMap.moveCamera()` will move the focus to the given location.

Check with your implementation.

Hope it helps:)

Comment: I think I found the problem. please see the updated question